# I asked a question "of" her

Tags: vocabulary

Random House dictionary (RHD) has these examples for: *[of](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of?s=t) (used to indicate derivation, origin, or source)*:

> I have a favour to ask **of you**. 
>   Don’t expect too much **of him**.

And I can add one from a Korean dictionary:

> I asked a question **of her**.

I can guess these of’s have this meaning: 
the complement of ‘*of*’ is an agent that will satisfy the subject’s hope or demand, from which they say ‘*of*’ is used do indicate origin or source. Can this be possible interpretation for those *of*’s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right, though I doubt any native speaker thinks of it that way, or "feels" it that way. In fact, a PP with *of* for the person questioned is very rare in US colloquial speech; it is mostly a literary construction.

Comment: I agree with your first point. I think native speakers just use this construction because they have been exposed to it, rather than taught it. However, I disagree with the statement that it is mostly a literary construction. I suppose *how often* one has heard the phrase plays a role in whether the construction is part of one's colloquial repertoire.

Comment: @CarSmack Yes, I got too focused on *question* and *favor*, which I only hear with *of* from academics: colloquially, in my experience, *question* almost always takes the NP, not the PP, and *favor* is more likely to use *from* than *of*. But *of* is I think more common than *from* with "expect".

Comment: At first, I would add this example, _I need to ask a question of you_, from Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s. But its example is not for ‘of’ but ‘ask,’ so I got an example from a Korean one, which says ‘of’ means ‘source,’ just as RHD says.